# How can I get my wifi card TP-Link TL-WN722N to work in Kali-Linux Oracle VM Virtual Box?

Tags: wifi, virtualbox, kali-linux

I enter `iwconfig` and receive:

```
root@gh0st:~# iwconfig
lo          no wireless connections

eth0        no wireless connections

root@gh0st:~# iwconfig
lo          no wireless connections
eth0        no wireless connections

root@gh0st:~#
```

I also enter in `ifconfig` and receive:

```
root@gh0st:~# ifconfig
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:15:1c:30
        inet addr:10.0.2.15 Bcast:10.0.2.255    Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe15:1c30/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
        RX packets:101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:11232 (10.9 KiB)   TX bytes:10886 (10.6 KiB)

lo      Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
        RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:960 (960.0 B)  TX bytes:960 (960.0 B)

root@gh0st:~#
```

I have already entered to make sure I have the updates

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

tl-wn722n is suppose to be plug and play?

I even tried `apt-get wicd` - nothing.

`lsusb`

```
root@gh0st:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:3002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:17cb ASUSTek Computer, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:3021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:3001 Linux Foundation 1.0 root hub
root@gh0st:~#
```

`ip link list`

```
root@gh0st:~# ip link list
1:lo <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT

    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mo
de DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:15:1c:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root@gh0st:~#
```

Answer (score 4):

I just solved the same problem and I'll try to share how I did it the best I can.

You see, the problem resides on the Virtual Machine (it aaaalways does). What happens is that your VM is most likely to be using **USB 1.0**, and the TL-WN722N uses **USB 2.0**. That's why, if you type down the command **lsusb**, you get to see the wireless card, but you don't get to see it if you use **iwconfig**.

So, to solve this, you must configure your Virtual Machine tu use **USB 2.0**. If you are using Oracle VirtualBox, for example, you will first need to install "oracle vm virtualbox extension pack" so you are able to use USB 2.0 and 3.0.

After that, you must configure your VM. To do so, go to the configuration window and into the USB tab. There, select USB 2.0. If you haven't created a **filter** for you WL-WN722N, do it now. It's important to do so, but I imagine you have already done it.

Finally, boot your Kali and once you're logged on, plug your WL-WN722N card. Kali will recognise it automatically. Type **lsusb** and **iwconfig** in order to confirm it.

Comment: I followed this guide and while the usb was disconnecting from host, it was not working on the VM machine, I read on another post and simply switched the port to another(USB 2.0 perhaps??) and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The TPLink device is connected to your host machine, not your guest. The guest VMs see a virtual Ethernet device, which explains what you can see in the output of `ip link` etc.

To allow the guest access to the physical USB device you need to set up USB Passthrough.

If the VM is off, open the VM's settings and select `USB`.  On the right hand side of the window you should see an icon of a USB connector overlaid with a plus sign.  Click on this and choose the TPLink device from the list.  It should now be available in the guest VM when you power up.

Alternatively, if the VM is already running, you can attach it from the VirtualBox VM's menu: Device -> USB Device -> TPLink...

Either way, `lsusb` should show the device.

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Only I've done this

Comment: And `lsusb` shows?  Also, if `lsusb` shows nothing, check the output of `dmesg` for anything relevant to USB or WiFi.

Comment: I have read everywhere, and I know in virtual box the USB section you need to select the TP Link and check it, Ive even loaded an older version of the Virtual Box to be able to run it in windows 8.1 and manually added the Vendor ID and Product ID.  Ill check the `lsusb` and garethTheRed thank you for taking the time to assist me.

Comment: My experience with this TPLink device and virtualbox is that the VM freeze in less than one hour when using it monitor mode. could be a virtualbox bug...