# TL-WN722N with Oracle VirtualBox on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am trying to setup the TL-WN722N connection over Ubuntu running in a Virtual Box. The later idea is to interface TL-WN722N with a cyclone V SoC running a lightweight Linux - Angstrom.

Right now, I have followed the steps/suggestions provided here:

[How can I get my wifi card TP-Link TL-WN722N to work in Kali-Linux Oracle VM Virtual Box?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193047/how-can-i-get-my-wifi-card-tp-link-tl-wn722n-to-work-in-kali-linux-oracle-vm-vir)

However, I could not get it working. I used `modprobe ath9k` to load the module manually because `dmesg | grep -e wlan -e ath9k` returned nothing. I could see the modules now using `lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ath9k                 147456  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              466944  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_hw,ath9k,ath9k_common
mac80211              782336  1 ath9k
```

`lsusb` returns the following :

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

and finally `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s3    no wireless extensions.
```

I have also tried adding filter using the Virtual Box option. When the atheros option is selected using Devices -> USB -> Settings : the following error is encountered :

```
Failed to attach the USB device ATHEROS USB2.0 WLAN [0108] to the virtual machine ubuntu_max.

USB device 'ATHEROS USB2.0 WLAN' with UUID {4a33886b-da96-4ef0-86f6-14e41c4326e5} is busy with a previous request. Please try again later.

Result Code: E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
Component: HostUSBDeviceWrap
Interface: IHostUSBDevice {c19073dd-cc7b-431b-98b2-951fda8eab89}
Callee: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Does anyone have a hand on this issue? The solution in the existing link does not really seem to help my issue here.

Details :

i) Host OS : Windows 7 Professional
   Guest OS : Ubuntu 16.04

ii) the host machine recognizes the device. I can also see the device in the Virtual box devices list. 
[image: Screenshot of the device recognized by Virtual Box]

Clicking on the device name results into error as mentioned :

```
Failed to attach the USB device ATHEROS USB2.0 WLAN [0108] to the virtual machine ubuntu_max.

USB device 'ATHEROS USB2.0 WLAN' with UUID {4a33886b-da96-4ef0-86f6-14e41c4326e5} is busy with a previous request. Please try again later.

Result Code: E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
Component: HostUSBDeviceWrap
Interface: IHostUSBDevice {c19073dd-cc7b-431b-98b2-951fda8eab89}
Callee: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

iii) Setup for the card was tried in the following ways :

- suggesstions as per the link mentioned in the question that required installing extension packages for the VirtualBox and enabling USB 2.0.
- installing drivers for atheros-firmware
- adding filter using the Virtualbox option .

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) clarify what OS the host machine is running and what version of Ubuntu you have in the guest; ii) explain if the card is correctly recognized by the host; iii) explain how you set up the card for the virtual machine.